# What takes precedence: an SPF record with "-all" in the primary TXT record, or one in the "include" section?

Tags: email, smtp, spf

Suppose I have a domain (company.com) with an SPF that looks like this:

```
v=spf1 ip4:70.70.70.70 include:host.marketing.com -all
```

and "host.marketing.com" looks like this

```
v=spf1 ip4:8.8.8.8 ~all
```

What takes precedence for company.com, the "~" or the "-"?   Does the tilde in the marketing company's SPF negate all SPF benefit for company.com?

Is this behavior consistent among all SPF parsers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that all parsers adhere to the [RFC4408](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4408.txt) specification, the `-all` from the company.com record applies. The include does not modify the verification process, it merely expands it to include the mechanisms contained in the included record.

If you were to use `redirect` in place of `include`, like this for company.com:

```
v=spf1 ip4:70.70.70.70 redirect:host.marketing.com -all
```

the `~all` would apply, and `-all` would be discarded in the verification sequence. That is, again, assuming that all parsers adhere to the specification

Comment: By my reading, this is verified with the table on page 18 that specifies a recursive check_host result of neutral causes the include mechanism to not match.